# Python - function returns true when a given number is a prime number or else false

Tags: python

Hi I'm a beginner and I'm stuck on this question that wants me to use only while loop to solve. The question wants me to write a function that returns True when the given number is a prime number and it returns False if the given number is not a prime number.

My code so far:

```
def is_prime(n):
    i = 2
    while i <= n//2:
        if n%i != 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        i+=1
```

The problem I have is I think my code displays the correct output for numbers 4 and above and it returns 'None' for 1, 2, and 3. I've debugged it and I think the problem is the while loop condition. But I don't know how to fix it. I would appreciate it if any of you pros can help me out!

edit:
I changed the while condition but 1 still returns None.. and 2 returns False when it's supposed to return True

```
def is_prime(n):
    i = 2
    while i <= n:
        if n%i != 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        i+=1
```

Comment: The `while` loop is not entered for values < 4, because of: `i <= n//2`. `3//2 = 1`

Comment: how can I fix it while making the rest of the code work?

Comment: Just add some simple condition(s) for n == 1, 2 or 3 before the while loop, and return accordingly.

Comment: First, you only need to go up to `sqrt(n)`.  Second, after 3, you can increment by 2, as even numbers are never prime.  For 1, it is defined as prime, so put that test in.  For 2 and 3, have `while i < max(math.sqrt(n),2):`

Comment: You have to let the `while` loop complete before you can return `True`; you are returning as soon as you've tested the first divisor. When `i` divides `n`, you can immediately return `False`; otherwise, you have to continue on to the next value of `i`. If the loop actually completes, *then* you can return `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import math;
def is_prime(n):
    i = 2
    while i < max(math.sqrt(n),2):
        if n%i != 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        if i == 2:
            i+=1
        else
            i+=2
```

Comment: is there any other way to do it without import math and max(math.sqrt(n),2)? my workbook haven't taught me those yet...

Comment: If your teacher penalizes you for using things you haven't covered yet, you have the wrong teacher.  But yes... have a while loop that increments `iMax` until `iMax*iMax>=n`.

Comment: In fact, you can start with `iMax = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You could hard-code these 3 cases, in case you dont want to use `sqrt`:

```
def is_prime(n):
    i = 2

    if n in (1,3):
        return True
    elif n == 2:
        return False

    while i <= n//2:
        if n%i != 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        i+=1

for x in range(1, 5):
    print(x, '=', is_prime(x))
```

Output:

```
(1, '=', True)
(2, '=', False)
(3, '=', True)
(4, '=', False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Want to get really fancy?  Make a Sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
def is_prime(n):
    a = list()
    # Assume all are prime
    a[0:n+1] = (n+1)*[1]

    # Start with removing even numbers
    i = 2
    while i*i <= n:
        print ("I: ", i)
        # Set all divisible by i to 0
        a[0:n+1:i] = len(a[0:n+1:i])*[0]

        # If a[n] is zero, return False
        if a[n] == 0:
            return False

        # Increment i until we have a prime number
        while a[i] == 0:
            i+=1

    if a[n] == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to impress your lesson teacher you can show him a fast probabilistic prime number isprime for numbers larger than 2**50. I haven't found any errors in it after weeks of cpu time stress testing it on a 6 core AMD:

```
import random
import math

def lars_last_modulus_powers_of_two(hm):
   return math.gcd(hm, 1<<hm.bit_length())

def fast_probabilistic_isprime(hm):
    if hm < 2**50:
       return "This is to only be used on numbers greater than 2**50"
    if lars_last_modulus_powers_of_two(hm+hm) != 2:
       return False
    if pow(2, hm-1, hm) == 1:
       return True
    else:
       return False

def fast_probabilistic_next_prime(hm):
   if hm < 2**50:
       return "This is to only be used on numbers greater than 2**50"
   if hm % 2 == 0:
      hm = hm + 1
   hm += 2
   while fast_probabilistic_isprime(hm) == False:
      hm += 2
   return hm

""" hm here is bitlength, which must be larger than 50.
    usage is create_probabilistic_prime(1000)
"""
def create_probabilistic_prime(hm):
   if 2**hm < 2**50:
       return "This is to only be used on numbers greater than 2**50"
   num = random.randint(2**hm,2**(hm+1))
   return fast_probabilistic_next_prime(num)
```

Comment: The source code will soon be here on my non probabilistic library here: https://github.com/oppressionslayer/primalitytest